# Idiom/saying for brokerage transaction costs - translation of German "Hin und her macht Taschen leer"

Tags: idiom-request

In German, we have a saying "Hin und her macht Taschen leer" meaning that doing lots of (investment) transactions means large accumulated fees.

A rough (almost literal) translation would be "[Investing] back and forth empties your pockets".

Is there any English idiom or saying like this?

Comment: We understand the concept but I know of no direct saying that is the same as this.  A related saying in English: "Lawsuits only make the lawyers rich".

Comment: Is this a finance term in German? Only finance?

Comment: @Lambie: I think so - I've never heard it other than refering to order fees for investments. In other contexts I'd use "management by potato: 'rin in die Kartoffeln, raus aus den Kartoffeln"

Comment: @cbeleites in the computer world we say (or used to say) "GIGO:  Garbage in, Garbage out."  Not quite the same as "Potato management".

Comment: Or like the W.C. Fields movie, "Never give a sucker an even break"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know of no such saying in English; but we do have a colloquial term for a broker's rapidly turning over a client's investments in order to generate transaction fees: ***churning***, which is not only unethical but illegal.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can think of, but it's not an idiom is

> There's a reason they're called "brokers", the commissions will make you broke!

meaning because a commission is paid to the broker for each trade, they are the ones who allays get paid (and bear no risk).  Commissions (and possible taxes) are a certain cost.

Comment: I think this is not quite what I'm looking for: I's read yours as warning to keep away from all dealings with brokers, whereas I'm looking for something that warns not to do short term trading - somewhat implying that long term investing is the way to go.